# How to click on all li elements in menu?

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I am trying to click on all links on top menu on site http://watirwebdriver.com/

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

class Proba
  def test
    b = Watir::Browser.new
    b.goto "watirwebdriver.com"
    b.ul(:id => 'menu-watirwebdriver-menu').lis.each do |li|
      li.click
    end
  end
end

proba = Proba.new
proba.test
```

But there is a problem raised:
https://gist.github.com/3239338

What could be a problem?

Comment: Note that clicking the lis will not actually do anything. If you want to click where the links navigate, you need to click the link inside the li.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your li aren't visible. Check if they are.

To click only on visible li, you can do this :

```
  def test
    b = Watir::Browser.new
    b.goto "watirwebdriver.com"
    b.ul(:id => 'menu-watirwebdriver-menu').lis.each do |li|
      li.click if li.visible?
    end
  end
```

Comment: It is the submenu lis that are not visible. If only the top level lis are wanted, it would be better to just get those - `b.ul(:id => 'menu-watirwebdriver-menu').lis(:xpath, 'li').each`. Then you do not need to make a visibility check.